# Why does my computer destroy a brand new USB stick in minutes?

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive

Since my English is not good, I use machine translation. This may be a strange sentence, but thank you in advance.

I connected a brand new USB stick to my computer and tried to use it as normal, but within minutes the USB stick was unusable.
I have three USB drives that were destroyed by connecting them to my computer.

These three corrupted USB flash drives have the following common symptoms:

- Windows Explorer recognizes it as a device but shows "no media".
- When I try to use Diskpart, it shows no media.
  When I check the status, "Read Only" is "No", but "Current Read Only Status" is "Yes".
- I could not use chkdsk either.
- The data recovery software said there could be physical damage to the USB stick.
- These appear to be nothing outwardly wrong.
- One of these is equipped with an access lamp. This stays on all the time when connected to a computer. (But I don't know the specifications of the access lamp of this USB flash drive, so it may be lit like this even when it is functioning normally.)

I have checked for excessive voltage or current being sent from the computer via a voltage/current checker to an external SSD that is not broken, and they are all within normal limits.
The only USB device that becomes unusable in this way is the USB memory stick; others can be connected and used without problems.USB flash drive tested with voltage and current checker is already broken. I have no more unbroken USB memory sticks
I bought 10 low capacity USB memory sticks to test this, so if this is not resolved by the time they arrive, I will check the voltage and current at the expense of these USB memory sticks.

I considered the possibility that the device driver is doing something bad, but since only microsoft, logitech, and wacom drivers are installed, I don't think this is the problem.

I do not want to know how to repair this broken USB memory, I want to know what causes it to break and take action. Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried to format the USB stick? Do these sticks work on a different PC? Also, try the steps in [this article](https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/how-to-fix-a-broken-usb-stick.html). If that doesn't help, please post (A) Windows version (B) PC model and maker

Comment: @1NN Hello.
The USB stick could not be formatted. Any way I try, I get "Please insert a disk" or "No media".
The Windows version is Windows 10 Pro 64bit 22H2.
My computer was assembled so I don't have a model number. Instead I write the parts I am using:
cpu : Intel Core i5-9400 CPU @ 2.90GHz
mother : board H310M PRO-VDH PLUS
graphic : NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
Storage
 465GB Crucial CT500MX500SSD1 (SATA (SSD))
 119GB SPCC Solid State Disk (SATA (SSD))
 465GB TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050 (SATA )
 465GB Seagate BarraCuda 120 SSD ZA500CM10003 (SATA (SSD))

Comment: What capacity do these sticks purport to be? How much data did you get onto them before they errored? Were they from a reputable high street store or ebay/amazon? Prime cause of this kind of error is a 128GB stick for an 'amazing' $£€ 10. Amazing mainly because they're fakes.

Comment: @Tetsujin Two of the three are klevv neo c20 16gb purchased in stores and one is RUF3-K128GA-BK/N purchased from Amazon and the seller is Amazon Japan LLC.

Comment: Most probably a driver problem, which makes windows "think" that you are connecting a card reader or a cd drive. You'll have to uninstall all old USB devices and associated drivers. This will vary according to your exact OS: Please edit the question and insert your Version of Windows, also as a "tag".

Comment: OK, 16GB are cheap enough anyway these days to not be worth faking, so it's less likely to be that.

Comment: this article should help you remove old device drivers: https://www.wikihow.com/Clear-the-Record-of-USB-Plug-in-Equipment

Comment: @1NN Thank you very much! I used this software software to uninstall the old driver. The already broken USB flash drive could not be used after following this procedure, but I will test it when the USB flash drive I purchased arrives.

Comment: I also recommend you make a malware scan, just to be sure

Comment: and check this article: https://7datarecovery.com/blog/usb-drive-shows-no-media/

Comment: @1NN Thank you! The malware scan did not detect anything:-)

Comment: If the problems are electrical in nature, be careful. A bad short circuit can fry your whole computer.

Comment: To test if drivers/system/software are faulty, simply try e.g. creating a live USB with something like YUMI/Rufus on another device and then switch your BIOS to boot from USB. If that fails, obvious hardware issue and a repair service should be contacted.

Comment: @harrymc Okay, thank you for letting me know!

Comment: @Destroy666 Thank you, Booting from another USB was no problem:-)

Comment: Ok, so I'd scan Windows with another good AV and if nothing gets detected on that Windows installation then reinstalling the system is what I'd personally do. Well, you could also try traditional fies such as `sfc /scannow`, `dism` and what not but I doubt they'll help. But messing around with drivers/system may cause more harm if something related to them is broken.